# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el src de un img de una página externa?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tenía la duda de como puedo obtener el src de un img de una página externa, en este caso es instagram. Adjunto foto de lo que quiero obtener:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es posible obtener ese src con php?

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente, después no se como seguir:

```
<?php
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
$pagina = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/p/CO9HJwTAvFl/');
```

Comment: Trata de abrir la imagen en una nueva pestaña hasta que quede sola la imagen y la URL termine en .jpg, .png, etc. Y solo copias esa URL y la pegas en tu etiqueta img en el atributo src

Comment: @Christian Si, podría hacerlo así. Pero lo que busco es que al poner un link de instagram automáticamente busque el src de ese img. Todos los img de instagram tienen el mismo atributo class="FFVAD", pero el atributo src distinto.

Comment: ¿Y cómo sabes cuál es la imagen que quieres? ¿Tienes un link que lleve a una página que sólo contenga esa imagen? ¿O tienes que extraerla de entre las imágenes contenidas en una página utilizando otro criterio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo eh conseguido resolver mi problema:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents($url);
echo $homepage;
$aux = explode('display_resources', $homepage);
$aux2 = explode('http', $aux[1]);
$aux3 = explode('"', $aux2[1]);
$imagen = "http" . $aux3[0];
$imagen = urldecode($imagen);
$imagen = str_replace('\u0026','&', $imagen);
echo $imagen;
```